# Basic linux kernel development and testing environment using qemu

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, qemu

I want to learn about the linux kernel and this is why I wanted a simple but powerful enough way test kernel changes that I do.

I used the info on this page https://mgalgs.github.io/2015/05/16/how-to-build-a-custom-linux-kernel-for-qemu-2015-edition.html to start.

So now I can start a qemu session with the kernel I choose and also have busybox utilities.

The part I cannot understand is how do I transfer a kernel module .ko on this virtual machine as to load it in my modified kernel ? I tried also transfering a c program by incorporating it in the initramfs but when I try to run the program I receive the following error message:
"/bin/sh: ./proc1: not found" .
Should I use a virtual hdd image ? If so how do I create and use one ? How do I transfer files from host os to the virtual hdd ?

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The created virtual hdd was not discovered because I didn't use **mdev -s** in the init file.
After that I could mount the sda in qemu session.

The c program that could not be ran I solved by compiling it with the -static flag.